Execution time UserPrincipal.GetGroups() increases with each call
I have an API request to synchronize users. In the synchronization function, I get from Active Directory the groups in which the user is included. The problem is that every time the request API is called, the execution time of GetGroups increases. Why can this happen and how can it be fixed?
I saw similar questions but didn't find a solution that helped me
var userGroups = userAd.GetGroups();

//userAd has type UserPrincipal
//userGroups has type PrincipalSearchResult<Principal>


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
